# Include vs. exclude specific cells in array in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to exclude specific rows in array commands in google sheets.

Here is some sample data:

| Exercise type | Weight | Unit | Reps | Success? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OHP | 40 | kg | 4 | yes |
| Deadlift | 240 | kg | 2 | no |
| OHP | 50 | kg | 10 | yes |
| Squat | 110 | kg | 12 | yes |
| OHP | 60 | kg | 5 | yes |
| Squat | 100 | kg | 6 | no |
| Squat | 90 | kg | 20 | yes |
| Deadlift | 200 | kg | 10 | yes |
| Deadlift | 220 | kg | 14 | no |

I can use the command `=ArrayFormula(MAX(IF($A$2:$A$999=A2,$B$2:$B$999)))` to create the variable `PR Max Weight`, but I want to use the variable `Success?` (column E) to filter the command for the variable `PR Max Weight` such that rows where `Success?` == "yes" are included in the array, and rows where `Success?` == "no" are NOT included in the array.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=max( filter(B$2:B, A$2:A = A2, E$2:E = "yes") )`